# Scrapy doesn't work for turning all the pages

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to crawl the whole product category, but it seems that it works well to some point and than it stops.

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
from Demo.items import DemoItem
class ProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name='black1'

    start_urls = [ 'https://octopart.com/search?category_ids=4215&start=0' ]

    def parse(self,response):
        items = DemoItem()

        for product in response.xpath("//div[@class='serp-card-header media']/div[@class='media-body']"):
            name =  product.xpath(".//a/span[@class='part-card-manufacturer']/text()").extract()
            ver = product.xpath(".//a/span[@class='part-card-mpn']/text()").extract()

            items['product_name'] = ''.join(name).strip()
            items['product_code'] = ''.join(ver).strip()
            yield items

        next_page = response.xpath("//a[contains(text(), 'Next')]/@href").extract_first()

        print next_page

        if next_page is not None:
            print next_page
            next_page_link = response.urljoin(next_page)
            print next_page_link
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_link, callback=self.parse)
```

And the outcome:

```
https://octopart.com/search?category_ids=4215&start=200 
2019-03-06 13:51:46 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (403) <GET https://octopart.com/search?category_ids=4215&start=200> (referer: https://octopart.com/search?category_ids=4215&start=190) 
2019-03-06 13:51:46 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <403 https://octopart.com/search?category_ids=4215&start=200>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
```

Comment: If they're blocking you halfway then it's likely they detected you're a bot. Have you set a custom user agent? And have you tried increasing [`DOWNLOAD_DELAY`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay)?

Comment: Yes, I have change the default user agent and the DOWNLOAD_DELAY is set to 8.0. Maybe it's better to use a list with a couple of different agents?

Comment: It might help. Ideally you'd want to see whether there is a message accompanying the 403 error in case there's an explicit reason, although that specific URL does open if I go only there. Does it always fail at that URL?

Comment: It fails at that URL and at the next few consecutives, but if I start crawling let's say from https://octopart.com/search?category_ids=4215&start=500 then it crawls a few pages and I got the same response back.

Comment: Maybe try randomising the order of the paging. It's easier to detect if you're going sequentially.

Comment: Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: This website enforces that the browser must have javascript enabled. At this point your best options probably are Scrapy-splash or Selenium